# Catch exception with specified error number

Tags: python

Error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I want to run something like:

```
try:
    #some code that may generate that error
except WindowsError.errorcode(2) as e:
    #handle error
```

I don't want to catch all Windows Errors, but just the ones with error code 2.

Maybe in a general 'except WindowsError', I can check the error code with an if statement, then if it's not number 2, I can rethrow e? That would do the same thing with more lines of code. I'm just not sure how to do that either way.

Is there a way to check the error code of an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

```
try:
    #some code that may generate that error
except WindowsError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        #handle it
    else:
        raise
```

I suggest importing [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#module-errno) and using the constants therein rather than using magic numbers; it's more self-documenting.  Also, reraising with a bare `raise` preserves the integrity of the stack trace.